# Woocommerce(wordpress) and opencart integration

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, opencart, woocommerce

I'm working in a project for a client in which I have to set up 5 different sites(in wordpress); each having a shop page. This client has an already existing online store built on opencart. Now they want me to set up these shop pages in 5 sites in such a way that they pull specific products(by category) directly from this opencart site. And every little features like shopping cart and checkout should be available in the individual sites without having to get redirected to the opencart site.

I've decided to use [woocommerce](http://www.woothemes.com/woocommerce/) here in these wordpress sites for the shop framework and developing another plugin that extends/overrides woocommerce functionality making it fetch not local data but shop data directly from the opencart database on different server.

Now I've thought about two different ways to do it:

1. Connecting directly with the opencart site database from wordpress sites and querying shop data based on criteria and show them on the shop pages.
2. Use some sort of REST api in opencart site (such as [this](https://github.com/zenwalker/opencart-webapi)) that enables other sites to retrieve shop data as JSON. And using this retrieved list to populate shop pages in these wordpress sites.

Most likely I would go for the second approach as I think its more easier and less redundant. But I don't know what consequences I might have to face; I don't know about any security vulnerabilities it might have. So, I don't know what is the best way to do it.

So, can anybody tell me what approach would be better here considering security and all aspects and why? And I want to know could there be any problems with the "REST api" approach? If you have any other better approach I would appreciate it too.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll start from the last option - using (REST) API. Though this is recommended and the cleanest way of accessing data from different website, it has also the biggest consequences:

- You are limited to services/methods it provides
- You are limited to data it provides
- the API You are pointing at is really the most lightweight I've ever seen **letting You only to read some few data** - but consider also the situation You'd need to update the products stock status and stock count, as well as their option's stock status. So You'd need to write some data back as well.

Your turn could be to fork this project and add Your own services letting You read more information and write some information back as well as extending the present ones to obtain more details on entities.

The first option - accessing directly the OpenCart's database - though not recommended nor very clean solution, it cannot be put aside or forgotten just because of the very simple yet powerful reason (with major responsibility) - freedom of accessing any data You need (and of course re-/writing any data You need - that's the major responsibility).

I cannot tell You that the first option is completely wrong nor that the second is the best You could go with as this would be opinion based answer. So think about it and consider also Your time schedule - writing a whole new (REST) API can double the development time. Decide whether You want to have direct access to all data for relatively the same development time or whether You have enough of time to build a clean solution using (REST) API meeting all Your (client's) needs. Optionally You may convince Your client to pay for cleaner and safer solution using (REST) API that would take some more time :-)